# How to deal with a player who makes oddball characters that don't fit the game?

Tags: problem-players

One of my best friends always makes....interesting characters. For example, in anyone else’s campaign he always uses home brew.

He takes his homebrew from d and d wiki and likes them because they’re different. All the time, he says it’s official because someone else made it and I always say it’s too op. I’ve talked to my friends and they all agree that him wanting to do these unbalanced homebrew is a problem.

Sometimes, he makes stuff up about what the race can do. For example, he played a bee forged in my friends campaign and he said he could memorize a map on the wall with his “photographic memory.” I said it wasn’t something in the race description but he started to say it was obvious that he had that ability since he’s a robot. The DM let it slide and he memorized it.

In another case, he wanted to pick a dragon race. I said he should just use Dragonborn but he wanted to fly. This race basically traded dragon breath for a flying speed of 60 ft.

I don’t think he's making these odd characters for the power, he’s doesn’t seem like the type of person to do that, he just wants to be creative. He can be creative, but he doesn’t need to be the odd one out.

Even in the GURPS game I ran, I wanted a realistic campaign. So he made a kid raised by wolves who had a stick in his mouth and he has a wolf brother that does whatever he says. I need help telling him that he needs to make, to put it bluntly, better characters. I want to tell this to him without him becoming mad/sad.

I have told him I don’t allow homebrew in my campaigns, but he keeps pitching odd characters and I had to cave.

Comment: This question to me deals more with a player using characters from homebrew sites than being disruptive.

Answer (score 3):

### Stand firm

It seems you have done everything right: talk to him, let him know the rules. I am sure that things in my campaign(s) and things in your campaign are very different. That's fine.

Don't cave.

If he wants to play his thing, he can run his own game.

### Same rules for all

Don't make any special "Bob rules", that takes you down a bad path. If he cannot abide by the rules you set for your campaign, there are other campaigns out there...